# Button background color in C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a problem. I know how to set a color for the button background color of when a user clicks it. [Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZfdA.png)

```
button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

However, if the user clicks it again, it will change the default color of the button. I would like to get the background color of the button pressed.

```
if(button.Background != (SolidColorBrush)(Colors.Blue))
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: `(SolidColorBrush)(Colors.Blue)` shouldn't compile.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZfdA.png
Can you help me??

Comment: That Image tells us nothing and seems only loosely connected to the question. Always post full error messages, and expected vs actual results.

Comment: As sort of a solution (workaround), try setting `button.Tag = "IAmBlue"` or `button.Tag = null`. Much easier in the `if()` later.

Comment: thank you so much . I will try it again.

Comment: thanks. I solved it. :)

Comment: Consider using a ToggleButton instead.

Comment: @XuânTrường - you can post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this code to be working in UWP apps.

```
 if (!toggle)
        {
            x = (SolidColorBrush)backButton.Background;
            backButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            toggle = true;
        }
        else
        {
            backButton.Background = x;
            toggle = false;
        }
```

Initially the value of toggle should be false (or true based on your logic).

**EDIT** :

In case you need to check the background brush before updating the color of the button you can use this code :

```
        SolidColorBrush originalBrush;
        SolidColorBrush newBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        private void backButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((SolidColorBrush)backButton.Background==newBrush)
            {
                backButton.Background = originalBrush;
            }
            else
            {
                originalBrush = (SolidColorBrush)backButton.Background;
                backButton.Background = newBrush;

            }
        }
```

Also if you are using many buttons using the **same** color you can use ToggleButton to achieve the same thing.

Comment: But where do you store the toggle?  For multiple buttons?

Comment: The toggle is a Boolean variable..you can define it in the class level.
For multiple buttons to do the same thing or you can check if the background color of the button is anything other than the 'x' SolidColorBrush and change it accordingly..

Comment: But How to do `if (... == Background)` is the core of the question.

Comment: Please see the **EDIT** .. I think this solves your problem ..!